# How can I detect secondary internet connections?

Tags: internet, hotspot, lan, intranet

I have a LAN. Is there a way, without installing any agent in each computer, to detect if any computer is accessing the internet without going through the LAN? For instance, via dongle, Wifi hotspot?

Comment: If the internet connection is not via your LAN you cannot detect it you are just watching the LAN.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is a security question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way from observing the LAN that you can do this.

What you need is a endpoint management system, such as Microsoft Intune, which can create policies for what devices (and users) are allowed to do or not. Denying connection to two different NIC's is a common setting.